# Как правильно проверить, существует ли запись БД?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Вопрос может и глупый, но я уже столько всего просмотрел, но ответа так и не нашел, и не много утомился, по этому не пинайте сильно за формулировку вопроса.

Подскажите пожалуйста. Использую базу данных MySQL и язык программирования C# (EntityFrameworkCore).

Я разбираю xlsx документ, беру из него по 10000 строк, складываю их в List и передаю в функцию записи.
Person это класс, со структурой таблицы Person MySQl.

Как правильно сделать проверку, существует ли такая запись в БД?
Или есть способ сравнить весь список целиком с данными в базе?

Так как если делать, проверку через

```
foreach(Person item in Persons)
{
   Person pers = context.Person.Where(x=>x.fullName==item.fullName && x.idFileTable==item.idFileTable).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Это будет долгий и упорный процесс.

Comment: Сделайте два множества из ключевых полей тех и этих сущностей. А потом что хотите делайте - пересекайте эти множества или там вычитайте, смотря какая у вас цель, что вы на выходе хотите получить.

Comment: Можно на таблицу повесить уникальный индекс и в случае совпадения ключа, по другому обрабатывать запись...

Comment: Чистый EF не умеет делать такие операции эффективно. Стоит посмотреть на какие-нибудь дополнительные библиотеки: [EF Core Tools & Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/) - ищем по терминам "bulk", "batch".

Comment: EFCore.BulkExtensions, Entity Framework Extensions, Entity Framework Plus и linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore умеют выполнять массовые операции, но я не в курсе, какие из них поддерживают MySql и какие имеют функционал "if not exists".

Comment: Или просто сделать это на чистом SQL. Создаём временную таблицу, заливаем туда данные батчами, джойним с основной таблицей для инсёрта.

Answer (score 2):

Посылать по одному запросу на каждого человека затратно. Всегда проще сделать 1 запрос в БД и после делать с данными что хочется.

Пример может не идеальный, но должно сработать как то так

```
var names = Persons.Select(x=>fullName).ToList();

var personsFromDb = context.Person.Where(x=>names.Contains(x.fullName)).ToList();

personsFromDb = personsFromDb.Where(x=>Persons.Any(item=>x.fullName == item.fullName && x.idFileTable == item.idFileTable)).ToList();
```

В итоге в personsFromDb останутся только те, кто есть в обоих списках.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect

Comment: @aepot не понял мысль

Comment: Пилим простой компарер и в один присест делаем `Intersect` вместо Where+Any. Это просто подсказка посетителям будущего.

Comment: @aepot я сделал в 2 этапа чтобы одним запросом в БД обойтись. Intersect разве сработает когда в бд шлешь запрос? Или он всю таблицу на клиента вытянет?

Comment: В последней строке кода уже нет никакой БД )

Comment: @aepot а, тепрь понял. По идее можно вообще сделать алгоритмически оптимальней, но не хотел усложнять.